# Add a Control Break when using a Group By on an Interactive Report - Oracle Apex v21.1

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Interactive Report on which I added a Group By function on the name of the article, with the office he is in and the department.

I tried to add a Control Break to the report which already have a Group By, but the option is no longer appearing

[image]

I tried to do it the opposite way, by adding a control break and then a Group By, but it's also not working.

Is there a way to do so or is it just impossible to Control Break a list with a Group By function ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully control breaked my report with a group by, by doing this :

- **include** the GROUP BY in the SQL

```
    SELECT  
            nom_article, 
            fk_categorie_article,
            pk_fk_etage_bureau, 
            pk_fk_service, 
            fk_batiment, 
            prix_net_article, 
            nom_departement, 
            nom_categorie,
            COUNT(nom_article) AS "QUANTITE"
    FROM vue_articles
    GROUP BY    nom_article, --here add the group by directly in the Query
                fk_categorie_article,
                pk_fk_etage_bureau, 
                pk_fk_service, 
                fk_batiment, 
                prix_net_article, 
                nom_departement,
                nom_categorie
    ORDER BY nom_categorie, nom_article ASC;
```

- Then add the Control Break to the report